# How to make it a single record in an efficient way

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying make it a single record as per partitioned column.

Is there any other efficient way of handling this scenario? please note query is written in redshift .

```
 Data:
    session_id,start_date,end_date
    123,2021-06-01 00:00:00.000000,2021-08-17 00:00:00.000000
    123,2021-08-18 00:00:00.000000,2021-08-19 00:00:00.000000
    123,2020-09-20 00:00:00.000000,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000000

Output:
123,2020-09-20,2021-08-19
```

Using this query i can get the result by filtering out rank=1

```
  with abc as(
    select 123 as session_id,'2020-09-20 00:00:00'::timestamp as start_date,
           '2021-05-31 00:00:00'::timestamp as end_date
    union
    select 123 as session_id,'2021-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp as start_date,
           '2021-08-17 00:00:00'::timestamp as end_date
     union
    select 123 as session_id,'2021-08-18 00:00:00'::timestamp as start_date,
           '2021-08-19 00:00:00'::timestamp as end_date
)
 select distinct
       session_id,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       last_value(end_date) over (
            partition by session_id
            order by end_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as new_end_date,
                 rank() over(partition by session_id order by start_date) as rank
from   abc
```

Comment: its redshift database

Comment: Efficient in what terms?  It looks like you want to pass literal data (embedded in the SQL) to a partitioned window function.  I suspect you want to do this for more than 3 rows.  How many rows (or KBs)?  Are your looking for execution efficiency or code simplicity or other?  There is no doubt that passing literal data into Redshift can be very slow/costly for data of any size due to the data being processed through the query compiler.  3 small rows of data is likely not a concern.  Please elaborate on question.